# No hot water at kitchen tap

Tags: plumbing

I've been having hot water problems of late. I have replaced all shut off valves in bathroom and kitchen, have installed new faucets throughout and replaced the dip tube BUT I'm still not getting any hot water at my kitchen sink (furthest away from tank).
I do get hot water in both bathrooms near the tank. 
Please help. Have had 2 plumbers in who havent been able to fix the problem. We have had no construction done that would require extra lines etc in several years.
Mary

Comment: What style home? Are you in a cold environment? Is it a single handle faucet? What is the water pipe made of? feel it's temperature before turning on water, then 2-4 minutes after turning it on, does the pipe ever get hot? If you shutoff the cold to that faucet, does water come out when the faucet is on?

Comment: Are you saying no water flows, or that water flows, but it is cold?

Answer (score 0):

What did the plumbers do / say?

Seems like you'd just remove the braided sink line coming from the hot shutoff under the sink and then test to see the water pressure and flow.

If they replaced the shutoffs, that implies they did the above and didn't get water flow, why they'd replace the faucets at the point seems like a waste of money.

If the shutoffs don't supply water then you have a problem somewhere between your hotwater tank and your kitchen faucet.

Could the pipe be frozen somewhere?  How cold is it where you are?